# How to pass multiple route parameters in twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, symfony-3.2

Hello I'm trying to send multiple parameters from twig like this

```
<a href={{path('myRoute',{'param1':param1,'param2':param2})}}>Link</a>
```

I have declare my controller as follows:

```
 /**
     * @Route("/categoria/{param1}", name="categoria")
     */
public function taskAction($param1){

}
```

But how can I send the second parameter and not including it in the route, so far what happens is that I get a rout like this

```
/categoria/param1?param2=1
```

and i expect a route like

```
/categoria/param1
```

and be able to access the second parameter but I don't want the second parameter appears in the route.

Comment: you can't pass a get param without seeing it in the url ...

Comment: ok, thanks @t-n-y i think i have to include it in the route or look for other option right?

Comment: it depends of your needs, i don't know what is this param. but you can pass it in the route or for exemple pass it in session ... it depends of your needs

Comment: all the params not defined in the route are accessible as query string parameters, as example `$request->get('param2');`

Comment: yes, my params are for example param1 = tools, param2 = 1 where param1 is my category name and param2 and id, so i just want a route when i can only show category name as /category/tools and not something like /categoriy/1/tools  @t-n-y

Comment: thanks @Matteo but what happens is that the param not included in the route appears as this /route/param1?param2=1 with the sintaxis using interrogation and equal signs

Comment: Please let us know what you are expecting

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what do you want but a possible solution would be:

Send an ajax request when you press the link with the parameters you want.
Then in your controller you will have something like this

```
public function taskAction(Request $request){

}
```

Finally return a response to your view

> Maybe giving some info about the functionality you want to achieve
>   would help us understand

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
/**
* 
* @Route("/category/{id}", name="category_delete")
*/    
public function myAction(Request $request, Category $category)
{
     $param1 = $request->get('param1');
     $param2 = $request->get('param2');
         .
         .
     $paramN = $request->get('paramN');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the first param as part of the route as you already did and you have to send a POST request when user clicks the link (using javascript) in order to send other params via post.
Check this as an example: 
https://gist.github.com/hellomedia/048906b9449463cd5792

or you can implement a similar logic as you wish.